# Error array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays

I've been trying to remove the first array element with PHP but I keep getting the following error:

> array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in path on line 62

I am a beginner in PHP so I really don't understand what I am doing. I would appreciate some help.

I use the following code:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <?php
            pre_r($_POST);
            if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                echo "Djur 1: " . $_POST["farmAnimals"][0] . "<br />";
                // Comment to myself - Don't forget to specify "index number"
                // - otherwise you get error Array to string conversion
                echo "Animal 2: " . $_POST["farmAnimals"][1] . "<br />";
                echo "Animal 3: " . $_POST["farmAnimals"][2] . "<br />";
                echo "Animal 4: " . $_POST["farmAnimals"][3] . "<br />";
                array_shift($farmAnimals); // line 62
            }
        ?>
        <div class="form">
            <h3>Please enter three kinds of animals you can find in a farm.</h3>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <p>Animal 1: <input type="text" name="farmAnimals[]" value=""></p>
                <p>Animal 2: <input type="text" name="farmAnimals[]" value=""></p>
                <p>Animal 3: <input type="text" name="farmAnimals[]" value=""></p>
                <p><input type="hidden" name="farmAnimals[]" value="Alpacka"></p>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
            function pre_r($farmAnimals) {
                // Selected a function to make it both easier to read in the code but also when printing.
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($farmAnimals);
                echo "</pre>";
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The updated code, which the first element is not being deleted:

```php
<?php
    pre_r($_POST);
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $farmAnimals = $_POST["farmAnimals"];
        echo "Animal 1: " . $_POST["farmAnimals"][0] . "<br />";
        // Comment to myself - Don't forget to specify "index number"
        // - otherwise you get error Array to string conversion
        echo "Animal 2: " . $_POST["farmAnimals"][1] . "<br />";
        echo "Animal 3: " . $_POST["farmAnimals"][2] . "<br />";
        echo "Animal 4: " . $_POST["farmAnimals"][3] . "<br />";
        array_shift($_POST["farmAnimals"]);
    }
?>
```

Comment: You haven't assigned anything to `$farmAnimals` when you try to shift something off it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you haven't set `$farmAnimals` as a variable.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

                echo "Djur 1: " .$_POST['farmAnimals'][0]. '<br />';
                // Kommentar till mig själv - Glöm ej specifiera "index numret"
                // -annars får du error  Array to string conversion

                echo "Djur 2: " .$_POST['farmAnimals'][1]. '<br />';
                echo "Djur 3: " .$_POST['farmAnimals'][2]. '<br />';
                echo "Djur 4: " .$_POST['farmAnimals'][3]. '<br />';
                array_shift($_POST['farmAnimals']);

            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($_POST['farmAnimals']);
            echo '</pre>';

 }
```

You need to change the array_shift to unshift the `$_POST['farmAnimals']` first key-value pair. You also don't need the pre_r function as it serves no purpose other than debugging which you don't need. Remove the pre_r function and simply print_r the `$_POST['farmAnimals']` AFTER the kay-value pair has been unset.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more on what you mean. Sorry Im quite new

Comment: replace your current array_shift with the one i've shown in the above code sample

Comment: I did that but the first element is still not being deleted.

Comment: check the new edit

Comment: Ok thanks the edit worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try array_shift($_POST['farmAnimals']) to remove the first item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing the PHP variable `$farmAnimals` and not the $_POST variable `$_POST['farmAnimals']`. Try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

                $farmAnimals = $_POST['farmAnimals'];
                echo "Djur 1: " .$_POST['farmAnimals'][0]. '<br />';
                // Kommentar till mig själv - Glöm ej specifiera "index numret"
                // -annars får du error  Array to string conversion

                echo "Djur 2: " .$_POST['farmAnimals'][1]. '<br />';
                echo "Djur 3: " .$_POST['farmAnimals'][2]. '<br />';
                echo "Djur 4: " .$_POST['farmAnimals'][3]. '<br />';
                array_shift($farmAnimals);

}
```

Comment: you array_shift isn't corrected

Comment: I guess it depends on whether Reebo0 is referencing $_POST['farmAnimals'] or $farmAnimals later in their code. I added a variable assignment before the echo statements.

Comment: you have a closed square bracket in your array_shift.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Edited.